# creating a custom getColor(byte r, byte g, byte b) method

Tags: java, colors, byte, rgb, 8-bit

i have a simple byte array that i want to take colours from. My plan was to have three bits from red, three bits for green, and two bits for blue. 8-bit.

I think the colours are right:

Please correct me if i'm wrong,

```
 byte[] colours = new byte[256]; //256 different colours, 8 * 8 * 4 
                                 //(3 bits(red) + 3 bits(green) + 2 bits(blue)
 int index = 0;
 for(byte r = 0; r < 8; r++){ 
    for(byte g = 0; g < 8; g++){
       for(byte b = 0; b < 4; b++){
           byte rr = (r & 255);
           byte gg = (g & 255);
           byte bb = (b & 255);
           colours[index++] = (rr << 5 | gg << 2 | bb);   
       }
   }
}
```

My goal is to make a getColor(byte r, byte g, byte b) like

```
public static byte getColor(byte r, byte g, byte b){
    return colours[return the right color using r g b];
}
```

But i don't know how. Here's where i need help.

I would like to rather not use the Color class if it's possible.

Other information: 
I'm using a BufferedImage.TYPE.BYTE.INDEXED to paint on.

Sorry if my english is bad :)

EDIT
Fixed where it was wrong

Comment: `colours[(rr << 5 | gg << 2 | bb)];` what is the purpose of this line?

Comment: Your `getColor` shouldn't be `void`, as it returns a value.

Comment: @ogzd It's an old technique using the individual bits of a larger value to store each channel.  You used to see this in old ASM code when dealing with things like Mode 13h

Comment: What is `int index`? It is never used.

Comment: `colours[(rr << 5 | gg << 2 | bb)];` names a location in the array colours, then does nothing with it. @ogzd is right, it seems odd.

Comment: Your getColor method returns void. What specifically should getColor return?

Comment: Fixed it, i was written this when i was tired : ) Made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `byte` is signed, represented in 2's complement, so you can't just shift that way.
From 128 on, you have to reverse the bit pattern, using negative values.

```
byte[] colours = new byte[256];

for(int i = 0; i < colours.length; i++){ 
    colours[i] = (byte) (i < 128 ? i : i - 256);
}
```

Your method should be something along the lines of:

```
public static byte getColour(byte r, byte g, byte b)
        throws InvalidColourException {
    if (r >= 8 || r < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Red is out of range.");
    if (g >= 8 || g < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Green is out of range.");
    if (b >= 4 || b < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Blue is out of range.");
    int i = (int) r << 5;
    i += (int) g << 2;
    i += (int) b;
    return colours[i];
}
```

Although, you could shrink it all to a single method, and discard the array:

```
public static byte getColour(byte r, byte g, byte b)
        throws InvalidColourException {
    if (r >= 8 || r < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Red is out of range.");
    if (g >= 8 || g < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Green is out of range.");
    if (b >= 4 || b < 0)
        throw new InvalidColourException("Blue is out of range.");
    int c = (int) r << 5;
    c += (int) g << 2;
    c += (int) b;
    return (byte) c;
}
```